# pub serve not updating web unless I restart it

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, dart-pub

In IntelliJ there's a tab that says "Pub Serve", when I hit Ctrl + Shift + R, I can see plenty of output on the Pub Serve output terminal and it launches the Chromium that came with the Dart Editor displaying my web application.

Now if I make a change to any of the dart files or html files or even index.html and refresh in Chromium, I don't see the changes until I click the stop button on Pub Serve.

I've installed the JetBrains plugin in Chromium to see if it makes a difference, non whatsoever.

Running pub serve from command line does exactly the same, until you kill it and re-run pub serve, your changes doesn't become visible.

Any idea on how I can have pub serve automatically reload upon code changes?

**Update**:

I think this could be related: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=21402

Comment: It usually does reload automatically. What OS and Dart version are you using?

Comment: Delete the `.pub` folder and try again.

Comment: It used to work for me as well, until I started using IntelliJ or maybe dart got updated. Versions: OSX 10.10.1 Yosemite and dart 1.8.3.
Does the same on an external command line. Going to try it in the Dart Editor now as well and see if it does the same.

Comment: Have you checked if deleting `.pub` changes anything?

Comment: deleted .pub as well as pub cache repair, still the same. Trying dart editor now to see if it does something different.

Comment: works fine in Dart Editor, mmm, wonder what dart editor does different.

Comment: Editing in IntelliJ while Dart Editor is serving it doesn't do anything either, if I make a change in Dart Editor and hit save, then only does it update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is caused by Safe Write, there's a temp workaround:

> WEB-13739 Pub Serve on Mac OS doesn't notice that file contents
>   changed, so refresh in browser shows old cached contents In DartEditor
>   you can work like this:
>
> 1. Start debug (this will start pub serve which takes a while).
> 2. Edit template in polymer element
> 3. Save (Now DartEditor does something to recompile the polymer template, AFAIK it does not do a full restart of pub serve because it
>      is faster).
> 4. Refresh browser, you see the change in the template.
>
> But in Webstorm 9 EAP October 8 version, this workflow is not
>   possible. I have to kill pub serve and restart in order to see my
>   change in the polymer component's template. I would like Webstorm to
>   work the same as DartEdtior so I can have the same save/refresh
>   development cycle.
>
> Workaround: uncheck 'safe write' mode in Preferences | Appearance &
>   Behavior | System Settings and vote for the corresponding issue in the
>   Google issue tracker.
>
> https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13739

This workaround is relevant to IntelliJ Ultimate as well.

Vote for bug fix here:
https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=21402

**Update**

Bug was fixed:

> This should be working now. The underlying issue was in the watcher
>   package, fixed here:
>
> https://codereview.chromium.org/861313006/
>
> Then pulled into the repo for pub and tested here:
>
> https://codereview.chromium.org/801943005/
>   https://codereview.chromium.org/870703003/

Thanks Bob!